# MacbookAir (21.04): resume from suspend very slow after recent update

Tags: suspend, macbook-air

Suspend and resume has been working on my MacbookAir for over 6 years now, and it continued to work normally upon update to 21.04. Some ensuing update created an issue where the resume (when pressing the power button) takes about ~30 seconds to kick in; the machine is literally unresponsive for ~30 second until it wakes completely normally.

There are a few strange things about this:

1. I say unresponsive, meaning the keyboard backlight is off and the screen is off. If I hold the machine up to my ear, however, I do hear the whir of the something happening immediately upon pressing the power button.
2. While for about ~30 seconds the keyboard backlight and screen are off, the keyboard does start sending keystrokes to the machine about 15 seconds in.
3. The machine resumes normally the first time after reboot, but has the delay in all subsequent suspend/resumes.

I did an experiment where I up pressed the power button for suspend, and then waited exactly 60 seconds until I pressed it again for resume. The final lines of syslog before the suspend are these.

```
Sep  4 22:40:55 praxis systemd-sleep[53765]: Suspending system...                
Sep  4 22:40:55 praxis kernel: [18668.791824] PM: suspend entry (deep)           
Sep  4 22:40:55 praxis gnome-shell[4696]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
```

The next lines in the syslog appear about 90 seconds after the last ones:

```
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.258872] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.263349] OOM killer disabled.               
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.263350] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.264842] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.271345] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status :     
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.271348] wlp3s0 Scan_results error (-22)    
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.282146] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.893668] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk    
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.914168] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked        
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18670.993742] pcieport 0000:05:00.0: quirk: cutting power to Thunderbolt controller...
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18671.329828] pcieport 0000:05:00.0: quirk_apple_poweroff_thunderbolt+0x0/0xd0 took 328240 usecs
Sep  4 22:42:26 praxis kernel: [18671.350207] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
```

I find it curious that these all appear to be suspend messages, as though the machine is not getting done with preparations before entering suspend.

Could somebody please help me debug this situation?
Would you know which package to report a bug against?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed with a recent kernel update.